# Share multiple message with ACTION_SEND

Tags: java, android, android-sharing

I'm a new at Android development and I'm trying to use ACTION_SEND. I have tried to look for an answer, I don't know if that's possible.

I would like to use ACTION_SEND to share 2 messages

I have used the following code without any success:

```
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent. ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareLink);
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareMessage);
            currentActivity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Sharing"));
```

Unfortunately, it sends one message with a concatenation of the two (the link + the text), what I would like is to be able to send two separate messages (of course without prompting the user twice).

Is that possible and if yes, how can I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE is as close as you will get

Comment: What are the two messages you want to send and what is the purpose of each? also can you share the code you use to receive the intent in your started activity?

Comment: I want to send a link (which is a location) and a text message, and I would like them to be sent seperately, and not concatenated

Comment: I dont believe that two successive putExtras would concatenate. Only the last one will have effect. And what do you mean by sending separately? I have no idea. And what would the receiver get?

Comment: It does concatenate if you change the type of the intent and not having them both as "EXTRA_TEXT". When i said send separately, I meant that I want the user to be able to share both a link and a message. For example if he decided to use Whatsapp or the Messaging app, it will show 1 message for the link and 1 message for the text. I saw some info to send multiple images, an image + text but couldn't find anything for a text + text.